# Java ASCII control codes to literal values

Tags: java, arrays, integer, character

I might be somewhat stupid here, but I can't seem to think of a straightforward solution to this problem.

I've currently got an int[] that contains ASCII character codes, however, with the ASCII table, any value < 32 is a control code.  So what I need to do is for any value > 32, put the ASCII character into a char[], however if it's < 32, just put the literal integer value in as a character.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] input = {57, 4, 31}; //57 is the only valid ASCII character '9'
    char[] output = new char[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] < 32) { //If it's a control code
            System.out.println("pos " + i + " Not an ascii symbol, it's a control code");
            output[i] = (char) input[i];
        } else { //If it's an actual ASCII character
            System.out.println("pos " + i + " Ascii character, add to array");
            output[i] = (char) input[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nOutput buffer contains:");
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(output[i]);

    }
}
```

Output is:

```
pos 0 Ascii character, add to array
pos 1 Not an ascii symbol, it's a control code
pos 2 Not an ascii symbol, it's a control code

Output buffer contains:
9 // int value 57, this is OK
```

As you can see the last two entries in the array are blank, as there isn't actually an ASCII character for either 4, or 31.  I know there are methods for converting `Strings` to `char[]`, however what's the general idea when you've already got a char[] in which you want the value.

There is probably a really easy solution for this, I think I'm just having a dumb moment!

Any advice would be appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Maybe the characters are printed blank?

Comment: Well the problem is that any int value in the ASCII table < 31 isn't an alphanumeric character, in that case I just want the literal value, e.g. '4' and '31'.

Comment: They actually are printed. The problem is that some of those control characters represented as int may have two digits, so they probably won't be chars...

Comment: Ahh yes of course, 31 isn't going to be a single character is it it's going to be '3' and '1'.  Good point, I don't think a char[] is the right way to go about doing this.  Thanks Mateusz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For classifying characters you should use the [Character.getType(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType%28char%29) method.

To store either a character or an integer you could try using a wrapper object to do that.

Alternatively you could wrap your `char` like this:

```
static class NiceCharacter {
  // The actual character.
  final char ch;

  public NiceCharacter ( char ch ) {
    this.ch = ch;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString () {
    return stringValue(ch);
  }

  public static String stringValue ( char ch ) {
    switch ( Character.getType(ch)) {
      // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters for what the Cc group is.
      // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character for a definition of what  are CONTROL characters.
      case Character.CONTROL:
        return Integer.toString(ch);

      default:
        return Character.toString(ch);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change how you print the output buffer

```
for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    if (output[i] < 32){
        System.out.println("'" + (int)output[i] + "'"); //Control code is casted to int.
        //I added the ' ' arround the value to know its a control character
    }else {
        System.out.println(output[i]); //Print the character
    }
}
```